# Facebook SDK Login Manager callback onCancel is called and also AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() return null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login with my android app. Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes instead of OnSuccess method OnCancel method of LoginManager callback is called and in such cases AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() also returns null. Following is code snippet of my Login Activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGson = new Gson();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login--" + loginResult.getAccessToken());
                        accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                        getUserDetails();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        if(!NetUtils.isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                            Toast.makeText(FBLoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_msg_no_network),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                            if(accessToken == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(FBLoginActivity.this, "Login unSuccessful..Please contact developer... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                getUserDetails();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                        if(accessToken == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(FBLoginActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            getUserDetails();
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Ensure that our profile is up to date
//        Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_fb);
        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayoutLogin);
        fbLoginButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.FBLoginButton);
        fbLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FBLoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));
            }
        });

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ApiEndPoints.BASE_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        mUserAPI = restAdapter.create(UserAPI.class);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and also include a description of what the user of your app does in those situations where this happens.